# Chart JS change pointBackgroundColor based on data value

Tags: colors, background, chart.js, point, linechart

So I have created a basic line chart using Chartjs. How would I go about changing the color of the points (pointBackgroundColor) depending on the value of the data? For example, if the data point is less than 10 it changes to red, or if the data point is between 10 and 20 it changes to blue?

```js
const CHART = document.getElementById("lineChart");  
let lineChart = new Chart(CHART, {
 type: 'line',
 data: {
  labels: ["5/10/2010", "5/11/2010", "5/12/2010", "5/13/2010", "5/14/2010", "5/15/2010", "5/16/2010"],
  datasets: [
  {
   label: "Theta",
   fill: false,
   lineTension: 0,
   backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
   borderColor: "rgba(9,31,62)",
   borderCapStyle: 'butt',
   borderDash: [],
   borderDashOffset: 0.0,
   borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
   pointBorderColor: "rgba(0,191,255)",
   pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,191,255)",
   pointBorderWidth: 5,
   pointBorderRadius: 5,
   pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
   pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
   pointRadius: 1,
   pointHitRadius: 10,
   data: [15, 28, 11, 3, 34, 65, 20],
  }
 ]
},
 options: {
 maintainAspectRatio: false,
 responsive: true,
 legend: {
  display: false,
 },
 scales: {
  yAxes:[{
  ticks: {
   fontColor: "#091F3e",
   beginAtZero: true,
   steps: 10,
   stepSize: 10,
   max: 100
   },
  gridLines: {
   display: false
  }
  
  }],
 xAxes:[{
  ticks: {
   fontColor: "#091F3e",
   fontSize: "10",
   },
  gridLines: {
   display: false
  }
  
  }]
 }
 }
});
```

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144864/can-the-colors-of-bars-in-a-bar-chart-be-varied-based-on-their-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure on any option and manipulate the returned value according to the context. In the example bellow I'm the `pointBackgroundColor` is red when the current value is greater then 0 and blue otherwise.

```js
pointBackgroundColor: function (context) {
  let value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];

  return value > 0
    ? 'red'
    : 'blue';
},
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is another thing that may help you [Change bar color depending on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968743/change-bar-color-depending-on-value).

Its original answer from [Tot Zam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4660897/tot-zam)
Adding the code sample in case the link doesn't work.

```
var colorChangeValue = 50; //set this to whatever is the decidingcolor change value
var dataset = myChart.data.datasets[0];
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
  if (dataset.data[i] > colorChangeValue) {
    dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.red;
  }
}
myChart.update();
```

Its about bars background, but you can try work around and find same solution.